# Loopback: Embedded Model is not working in offline sync

Tags: node.js, synchronization, offline, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have followed the [loopback offline sync](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-offline-sync) example and create my own model with embedded document.
I created a Model named Project where ProjectMembers are embedded model. Here are my model:
Project.json

```
{
    "name": "Project",
    "base": "PersistedModel",
    "strict": "throw",
    "persistUndefinedAsNull": true,
    "trackChanges": true,
    "properties": {
        ...
     },
    "relations": {
       "members": {
            "type": "embedsMany",
            "model": "ProjectMember",
            "property": "members",
            "options": {
               "validate": true,
               "forceId": false
            }
          }
    }
}
```

ProjectMember.json

```
{
    "name": "ProjectMember",
    "base": "Model",
    "idInjection": true,
    "properties": {
        ...
    },
    "validations": [],
    "relations": {},
    "acls": [],
    "methods": []
}
```

In the server side model-config.json I updated the datasource as below:

```
"Project": {
    "dataSource": "my_db"
},
"ProjectMember": {
    "dataSource": "transient"
}
```

And in the client side in lbclient/models/ I added 2 files local-project.json and remote-project.json as exactly same as local-todo.json and remote-todo.json.
I updated the client side model-config.json file as below:

```
"RemoteProject": {
    "dataSource": "remote"
},
"LocalProject": {
    "dataSource": "local"
}
```

In the client controller I run the following codes:

```
ProjectModel.create($scope.project)
.then(function(project) {
    var owner = loginDetails.getLoginUser();// the member
    owner.role = 'owner';
    owner.status = 'active';
    project.members.create(owner); //shows error: couldn't read property  

    $scope.project = {};
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

It creates the Project but failed to create the embedded model. It displays "Couldn't read property create undefined"? Is there any way to create embedded model in the client side?

**UPDATE**
The embedded model works only on server side. But when the browserify create the browse.bundle.js, it fails to add the embedded model.

Comment: can you share the error log for "Couldn't read property create undefined"?

Comment: here is the error log:  
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the trial and error method and has come to a solution about offline embedded model.
As previously,I only defined the relations between Project and ProjectMember in the "common/models/" directory. What I find is, I have to define the relations in the client side model too. So I did the following steps and it works.

1. I created a json file - "lbclient/models/local-project-member.json".

   ```
   {
     "name": "LocalProjectMember",
     "base": "ProjectMember"
   }
   ```
2. Added the following lines in "lbclient/model-config.json".

   ```
    "LocalProjectMember":{
       "dataSource": "local"
     }
   ```
3. Modified the "lbclient/models/local-project.json" file as below.

   ```
   {
    "name": "LocalProject",
    "base": "Project",
    "relations":{

      "members": {
        "type": "embedsMany",
        "model": "LocalProjectMember",
        "property": "memberList",
        "options": {
          "persist": true,
          "validate": true,
          "forceId": false
        }
      }
    }
   }
   ```

So the conclusion is if you want your embedded model work on offline you have to redefine the relations in the client side model.